# List or Browse Clusters in OrientDB Studio

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I am looking for a way of getting a list of clusters and also the record count in that cluster. My requirement is for OrientDB Studio.

The console version of what I am looking to achieve would be `list clusters` or `cluster`

I have looked around the ODB documents and have gone through all aspects of the Studio app, but can't seem to find an answer for my issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can see clusters in studio on the "Schema" tab.

Comment: I am running studio 2.2.19. In the "Schema" Tab, I see 3 sections. Vertex Classes, Edge Classes and Generic Classes. The Vertex Classes has a tab for "System Classes". Additionally, one of the the columns of Schemas is Default Cluster. However, what I am looking for is a class level cluster that is created via `Alter someclass addcluster newcluster`. Typically, I can query the cluster directly via `select from cluster:newcluster`. I am looking for a list of these clusters specifically.  Can you please let me know exactly where in the "Schema" tab, I can find a list of added clusters?

Answer (score 1):

You can see clusters IDs, names and records amounts in studio on the "DB" tab.